# Using [Authorize] with OpenIdConnect in MVC 6 results in immediate empty 401 response

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, action-filter, openid-connect

I'm trying to add Azure AD authentication to my ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 application and have followed this [example on GitHub](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIdConnect-AspNet5). Everything works fine if I put the recommended code in an action method:

```
Context.Response.Challenge(
    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

However, if I try using the `[Authorize]` attribute instead, I get an immediate empty 401 response.

How can I make `[Authorize]` redirect properly to Azure AD?

My configuration is as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    ...
    services.Configure<ExternalAuthenticationOptions>(options => {
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    });
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
    ...
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(options => {
       options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
    });

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options => {
        options.ClientId = Configuration.Get("AzureAd:ClientId");
        options.Authority = String.Format(Configuration.Get("AzureAd:AadInstance"), Configuration.Get("AzureAd:Tenant"));
        options.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300";
        options.PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration.Get("AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri");
        options.Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
            AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
        };
    });
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To automatically redirect your users to AAD when hitting a protected resource (i.e when catching a 401 response), the best option is to enable the `automatic` mode:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options => {
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;

    options.ClientId = Configuration.Get("AzureAd:ClientId");
    options.Authority = String.Format(Configuration.Get("AzureAd:AadInstance"), Configuration.Get("AzureAd:Tenant"));
    options.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300";
    options.PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration.Get("AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri");
    options.Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications {
        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
    };
});
```

Comment: I actually had `options.AutomaticAuthentication = true`, but just for `app.UseCookieAuthentication` (updated my question). Adding this to `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` as well did the trick. Thanks!